# Can I use a reversable drone BL_Heli ESC directly from a PWM receiver?

Tags: esc-protocol

If I wanted reversable brushless motors in a boat or robotics project, where I don't have a flight controller to handle DSHOT communications, could I use BL_Heli ESCs?

Do they still understand PWM signals? Do they need configuration?

This is largely because I don't want the brake and reduced speed reverse that car ESCs have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about BLHeli, but you should be able to use BLHeli_S in "3D mode" with PWM. They do need configuration, you will have to set motor direction to bi-directional.